# How do I get CMake to find my test in my C library project?

Tags: unit-testing, cmake

I have a project here:
https://github.com/edhartnett/ncglm

It is a small C library for reading netCDF data files from the Geostationary Lightning Mapper. I have an autotools build which works fine, and I'm trying to add a CMake build.

The directory structure is simple, there is a main directory, a src directory, and a test directory.

In the main directory I have:

```
# This is the main cmake file for ncglm, a library to help read the
# netCDF data files from the Global Lightning Mapper (GLM) instrument
# on GOES-16 and GOES-17.
#
# Ed Hartnett 11/10/19

# This will use any cmake between 3.1 and 3.15, preferint later
# versions with updated policies.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.15)
if (${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.12)
  cmake_policy(VERSION ${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION})
endif()

# set the project name
project(ncglm VERSION 1.0)

#Add custom CMake Module
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/"
  CACHE INTERNAL "Location of our custom CMake modules.")

# Find netCDF.
include(FindNetCDF)

include_directories("${NETCDF_INCLUDES}")

# Create a config.h.
configure_file(config.h.cmake.in config.h)

# Turn on testing.
enable_testing()
include(CTest)

# Build in this subdirectory.
add_subdirectory(src test)
```

In the src subdirectory I have:

```
# This is the cmake file for the src directory of the ncglm library.

# Ed Hartnett 11/10/19

# Build the ncglm library.
add_library(ncglm glm_read.c goes_glm.h glm_data.h)
```

In the test directory I have:

```
# This is the cmake build file for the test directory of the ncglm library.
#
# Ed Hartnett 11/10/19

enable_testing()
add_test(NAME tst_glm_read COMMAND tst_glm_read)
build_test(tst_glm_read)
add_sh_test(nc_test4 run_glm_tests)
```

When I build, I get:

```
ed@mikado:~/ncglm/build$ cmake -DNETCDF_INCLUDES=/usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.2_hdf5-1.10.5/include -DNETCDF_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.2_hdf5-1.10.5/lib .. && make test
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found NetCDF: /usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.2_hdf5-1.10.5/lib  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ed/ncglm/build
Running tests...
Test project /home/ed/ncglm/build
No tests were found!!!
```

How come cmake is not trying to build or run my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> add_subdirectory(src test)

This is invalid / it doesn't do what you think it does. What you want to do is:

```
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

The cmake website is down right now, I can't link to it. From memory the `add_subdirectory(src test)` reads CMakeLists.txt in the `src` source directory, but builds the sources in the `test` build directory, the `test` is created inside the build directory inside `CMAKE_CURRENT_BUILD_DIR`. To add two source directories, you have to use two [`add_subdirectory()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html).